# reading a barcode with a webcam

Tags: c#, webcam, barcode

Hey,
I'm trying to read a EAN-13 barcode from my webcam.
I already wrote a class to do that work.
I'm taking a picture from my webcam, trimming it to show ONLY the barcode,
and reading the barcode with the code tables from wikipedia.
For some reason, the barcode gets trimmed, but the output is always "0-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1".
I wonder if i did any stupid mistake or misunderstood something?

I do not want to use ANY third-party programs!

this is my code for now:

```
    public class BarcodeDecoder
{
    static string[] ligerade = new string[] { "0100111", "0110011", "0011011", "0100001", "0011101", "0000101", "0010001", "0001001", "0010111" };
    static string[] rechtsgerade = new string[ligerade.Length];
    static string[] liungerade = new string[ligerade.Length];
    static string[] GeradeUG = new string[] { "UUUUUU", "UUGUGG", "UUGGUG", "UUGGGU", "UGUUGG", "UGGUUG", "UGGGUU", "UGUGUG", "UGUGGU", "UGGUGU" };
    static int[] links;
    static int[] rechts;
    static string result;

    public static string Decode(Bitmap b)
    {
        result = "";
        Bitmap bb = CutOutOf(b, b.Height / 2);
        bb = trimBitmap(bb);
        int[] lgs = GetNumberOutOf(bb);
        int[][] rr = trimArray(lgs);
        links = rr[0];
        rechts = rr[1];
        FillArrays();
        BearbeiteLinks();
        BearbeiteRechts();
        return result;
    }
    static void BearbeiteLinks()
    {
        string GU = "";

        string[] zahlen = new string[6];
        zahlen[0] = OutOfArray(links, 0, 7);
        zahlen[1] = OutOfArray(links, 7, 7);
        zahlen[2] = OutOfArray(links, 14, 7);
        zahlen[3] = OutOfArray(links, 21, 7);
        zahlen[4] = OutOfArray(links, 28, 7);
        zahlen[5] = OutOfArray(links, 35, 7);

        foreach (string pq in zahlen)
        {
            bool gerade = ligerade.ToList().IndexOf(pq) > -1;
            if (gerade)
            {
                result += ligerade.ToList().IndexOf(pq).ToString();
                GU += "G";
            }
            else
            {
                result += liungerade.ToList().IndexOf(pq).ToString();
                GU += "U";
            }
        }
        result = GeradeUG.ToList().IndexOf(GU).ToString() + result;
    }
    static void BearbeiteRechts()
    {
        string[] zahlen = new string[6];
        zahlen[0] = OutOfArray(rechts, 0, 7);
        zahlen[1] = OutOfArray(rechts, 7, 7);
        zahlen[2] = OutOfArray(rechts, 14, 7);
        zahlen[3] = OutOfArray(rechts, 21, 7);
        zahlen[4] = OutOfArray(rechts, 28, 7);
        zahlen[5] = OutOfArray(rechts, 35, 7);

        foreach (string pq in zahlen)
        {
            result += rechtsgerade.ToList().IndexOf(pq).ToString();
        }
    }
    static string OutOfArray(int[] ar, int startindex, int length)
    {
        int[] gar = new int[length];
        Array.Copy(ar, startindex, gar, 0, length);
        StringBuilder bilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < gar.Length; i++)
        {
            bilder.Append(gar[i].ToString());
        }
        return bilder.ToString();
    }
    static Bitmap trimBitmap(Bitmap b)
    {
        bool alreadyBlack = false;
        int firstblack = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < b.Width; i++)
        {
            Color gp = b.GetPixel(i, 0);
            if ((gp.R + gp.G + gp.B) / 3 < 128)
            {
                if (!alreadyBlack)
                {
                    alreadyBlack = true;
                    firstblack = i;
                }
            }
        }

        bool alreadyblack = false;
        int lastblack = 0;
        for (int i = b.Width -1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            Color gpp = b.GetPixel(i, 0);
            if ((gpp.R + gpp.G + gpp.B) / 3 < 128)
            {
                if (!alreadyblack)
                {
                    alreadyblack = true;
                    lastblack = i;
                }
            }
        }
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(lastblack - firstblack, 1);
        for (int i = firstblack; i < lastblack; i++)
        {
            Color c = b.GetPixel(i, 0);
            result.SetPixel(i - firstblack, 0, c);
        }
        result.Save("C:\\result.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return result;
    }
    static int[][] trimArray(int[] ar)
    {
        int[][] res = new int[2][];
        int[] resl = new int[6 * 7];
        int[] resr = new int[6 * 7];
        Array.Copy(ar, 2, resl, 0, 6 * 7);
        Array.Copy(ar, 2 + 6 * 7 + 5, resr, 0, 6 * 7);
        res[0] = resl;
        res[1] = resr;
        return res;
    }
    static void FillArrays()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ligerade.Length; i++)
        {
            rechtsgerade[i] = string.Concat(ligerade[i].Reverse());
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < liungerade.Length; x++)
        {
            liungerade[x] = Invert(rechtsgerade[x]);
        }
    }
    static string Invert(string xx)
    {
        string xs = "";
        for (int y = 0; y < xx.Length; y++)
        {
            int fd = int.Parse(xx[y].ToString());
            if (fd == 0)
                fd = 1;
            else
                fd = 0;
            xs += fd.ToString();
        }
        return xs;
    }
    static Bitmap CutOutOf(Bitmap b, int y)
    {
        Bitmap res = new Bitmap(b.Width, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < b.Width; i++)
        {
            Color c = b.GetPixel(i, y);
            res.SetPixel(i, 0, c);
        }
        return res;
    }
    static int[] GetNumberOutOf(Bitmap bb)
    {
        List<int> intlst = new List<int>();
        float f = (float)bb.Width / 95.0f;
        float wd = f / 2.0f;
        for (float i = wd; i < bb.Width; i+=f)
        {
            Color c = bb.GetPixel((int)Math.Round(i,0), 0);
            intlst.Add(GetOutOfColor(c));
        }
        return intlst.ToArray();
    }
    static int GetOutOfColor(Color c)
    {
        if (c.A + c.B + c.R > 128 * 3)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Sorry for german names in the code!

Comment: why dont you debug just one method at a time ? BTW: trimArray should have a signiture like trimArray(int[] ar, out int[] res0, out int[] res1) and don't use public static members so often

Comment: Well everything works fine but the static int[] GetNumerOutOf(Bitmap bb)... returns junk! I dont know why. It should return an Array[95] with the binary code of the barcode

Comment: Are you sure your webcam has a high enough resolution to be able to extract an EAN13 barcode. What dpi / resolution are you working with as you need to be able to recognise 4 different black bar widths and 4 different white bar widths from memory.  If you have trouble reading a barcode try upping the image quality / resolution to see if you can get the correct result.

Comment: I think the problem has nothing to do with the resolution, more with the fact that my webcam has no autofocus. I always have to focus it myself which is not always the most perfekt result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems:

1) You only scan the top most pixel row of your image (see the second parameter of *GetPixel*). Your barcode is probably in the middle of the image and not at the top.

```
Color c = bb.GetPixel((int)Math.Round(i,0), 0);
```

2) Instead of the green component, you take the alpha component to convert the colored pixel into a binary value. Since the alpha component is probably always 255, you always get 0 unless you have a very dark pixel.

```
if (c.A + c.B + c.R > 128 * 3)
```

Comment: Yeah its the top most row out of the already cut bitmap.
See trimBitmap(). The second idea isn't bad at all. I'll give it a try