# Barcode Reader thru Webcam in C# (WPF or ASP.Net/Silverlight)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, barcode-scanner

I have a bit of a problem. I was researching for a good 3rd party application that will let me read Barcode (128) specifically but I notice most of it has a licensce that is needed to be bought.

[.NET BarCode Reader in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959383/net-barcode-reader-in-wpf)
From this conversation, I know .Net does not have any class for support 
but my question are there a free 3rd Party Application or can I just do my own?

I did not get how she did it but someting like this  [reading a barcode with a webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845721/reading-a-barcode-with-a-webcam)

In the end I want to make an application similar to this (It is using silverlight)
https://www.vintasoft.com/Silverlight_Webcam_Barcode_Reader_Demo.html

But if you will try the demo, the last three barcode numbers will be asterisk. Because I need to buy to licensce to get full :(

Thanks for those who can help

Comment: Check out this link for what kind of questions you should use StackOverflow for http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ... specifically "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Use `WPF MediaKit` for capturing barcode using device camera.

step 2: Use `Zxing` for parsing that barcode image.